# Dillema with prediction with TensorFlow on MNIST set

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, scikit-learn, computer-vision

currently I am a newbie on TensorFlow, I have trained a model using MNIST set and now I have made some pictures with numbers and I want to try to test the precision. I think I have a syntax or understanding of how things in TensorFlow are working
This is my model:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
def weight_variable(shape):
initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

#stride 1 and 0 padding
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

#pooling over 2x2
def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
# Second Layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
#Fully connected layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
#Readout layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(200):
   batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
   if i%100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
   train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

# Here is my custom dataset

custom_data=GetDataset()

print sess.run(y_conv,feed_dict={x: custom_data})
```

It is not the right syntax for making prediction with my custom data ? I am missing something here ? My data are in the same format as the one from the MNIST set but I can find a correct syntax for how to make a prediction:

```
print sess.run(y_conv,feed_dict={x: custom_data})
```

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y_conv` will provide you what you need to make recommendations. You're probably just not understanding the form the data takes on in that tensor.

In your code you have a loss function and an optimizer:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
   tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Note that you pass `y_conv` to the `softmax_cross_encropy_with_logits` method. `y_conv` at this point is an unscaled number. Negative values represent the negative class, positive values represent the positive class.

`softmax` will convert these to a probability distribution over all outputs. This notably converts all outputs to a [0,1] range. Cross entropy then computes the error (cross entropy assumes values in the [0,1] range).

It's common to simply create another tensor that actually computes the prediction, if you're using softmax then:

```
prediction = tf.softmax(y_conv)
```

That would give you the predicted probability distribution over the labels. Just request that tensor in your `sess.run` step.

If you just care about the most probable class, then you can take the max of the `y_conv` values. Note also that if this statement is true you might want to experiment with `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` which is a slightly more tuned to producing results that are not a probability distribution (slightly better for single class prediction, and mandatory for multi class prediction).

Comment: Hi David,  thanks for the quick and explicit answer. Unfortunate, this seems not no work.  I have added the following lines in the code: "prediction = tf.nn.softmax(y_conv)" before the sess.run line in my code and "print sess.run(correct_prediction,feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})" at the end for trying to print the prediction but I get the error: "InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_40' with dtype float
  [[Node: Placeholder_40 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]"

Comment: That's a different issue, you have a placeholder to pass data in and you're not feeding it the data. First name your placeholders so the error message points you to the right place. It's probably your labels are being used somewhere. You don't need to feed the placeholder if the OP you request doesn't friend on it, but it's easy to have a dependency you didn't notice.